# Flex trace() doesn't print

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

There's a lot of examples for ActionScript over the web using trace() to print results.

I'd tryied it using Flash Builder 4, but it don't print to the console. Where can I see the output?

Comment: We need to see some code

Comment: @Woot4Moo public class Hi { public function Hi() {trace("hi");}}

Comment: It's certainly not graceful, but if you want to test without debug mode and don't have a whole lot you need traced, mx.controls.Alert.show("blah blah blah");

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Are you in debug mode ?
2. Put a breakpoint on the line where the trace() is wrote (ctrl+shift+b), debug and see if the trace is reached.
3. Are you printing the right string? try to use also a static text in front when doing trace like `trace("Loading file: ", _myFile.url);`

Comment: So it just prints to console in debug mode (crap)..  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to use Flash Player debugger, but you want to log messages without annoying Alert popups, you can easily
[log to the Firebug console.](http://carrythezero.net/blog/2010/02/17/flex-simple-logging-to-the-firebug-console/)

Comment: Dead link, perhaps this is equivalent information? http://marumushi.com/news/debugging-as3-with-firebugs-console

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are running the debug build and not the release build?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem even with the debug player.  I could step right past a `trace` call in the debugger with no console output.  I was pulling my hair out checking `mm.cfg`, `flex-config.xml`, `.actionScriptProperties` and all the options I could find in FlexBuilder.  Nothing worked...

..until I rebooted my machine (Windows XP 64-bit).  No other changes necessary!