# Action Script 3 (AS3) Trace not working

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, trace

Hello guys i have very big problem with Action Script 3 trace function?

Here is my code and it dont work..

Output is empty.

```
trace("HI");
```

Can someone tell me fow to fix it?

I have tryed to find answer in some search engines but i was unable to found

Im Using Adobe Flash Cs 5.5

Yes i can make something on as3 but i cant test on as3

Comment: Could you provide some more code where you are trying to use that line.

Comment: Fin Flex im making new document and just clicking F9 then typing this code and nothing appears i have found this bug but now im going to make a game so i need the trace

Comment: Make absolutely sure you are on frame 1 when you try to add the AS3.

Comment: You need to DEBUG and not RUN your code to see the trace. Possible duplicate of this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479087/flex-trace-doesnt-print/3479145#3479145

Answer (score 2):

Traces will only appear if you run it in debug mode, not if you simply "run" it. This might be the issue? I can't remember how flash cs5.5 does it when you run with F9.

Comment: I am trying to run it but it don't works.I have found the solution.So here is it i must go to the right top corner on output window and make the filter to Verbose

Answer (score 2):

Hey guys i found the solution :)
Go to the top right corder of the output window and click on the list icon, then make the filter to Verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check that **"Omit trace statements"** is **NOT checked** in the Publish Settings

Answer (score 0):

seems you are PUBLISHING (<kbd>f12</kbd>), when you should have used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (Control > Test Movie). If you are really publishing (outside of the Flash IDE), the Output Panel will never shows anything.