# Where is console in Flash Builder 4.7

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I'm new to ActionScript development and am trying to create a simple Hello World program. Here is the code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class HelloWorld extends Sprite
    {
        public function HelloWorld()
        {
            trace("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

Then I try to run this and a blank white window pops up. But at the bottom of FB there is no Console window! I tried going to Window->Show View->other->Console and that puts a console tab at the bottom of FB but it now looks like there are several types of Consoles: Java stack trace console, Maven console etc. I just want to debug my program and see my trace output. What do I do?

Comment: Are you sure you are testing the movie? `trace` doesn't work when running it on Release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question may be a duplicate of  [Flex trace() doesn't print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479087/flex-trace-doesnt-print/3479145#3479145)

Please make sure you Debug and not Run your project (in Windows shortcut is F11)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the SWF isn't being opened in the debug version of Flash Player.

http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

- For IE, install the Active X debug player.
- For Chrome, install the "Plugin" debug player, then go to chrome://plugins and make sure the built in "PPAPI" version is disabled.
- For other browsers, just installing the "Plugin" debug player should work.

In Flash Builder, you can change the browser in Window > Preferences.